# set current time for audio as soon as it loads

Tags: jquery, audio

i wanted to make a music player which plays through navigation but it was recommended to save the current time in cookies and then use them to set current time for audio as soon as a new page loads.
but i am not able to set the current time for audio as soon as it loads. please help

`myaud.onloadeddata=currentTime=15;
    myaud.oncanplay=currentTime=15;
    $("#audioDemo").bind("load",function(){
       myaud.currentTime=10;
    });
    $('#audioDemo').load(function(e) {
       myaud.currentTime=10;
    });`

All these dont seem to work. And the variable is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myaud").on("canplay", function() {
    var currentTime = $.cookie("currentTime");

    if(currentTime == null) {
        $("#myaud").currentTime = 0;
    } else {
        // Set Current Time as cookie value
        $("#myaud").currentTime = currentTime;
    }
});

// Set Current Time cookie when player paused or something else
$("#myaud").on("pause", function() {
    $.cookie("currentTime", $(this).currentTime);
});
```

- It is recommended to use 'on' method for jquery.
- In case of **jquery cookie** feature, please refer [this library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works but the audio stops at 10 seconds. Like, just hangs at the 10th second. But it does start at the 10th second so, thats something?

Comment: quick update, it doesnt happen in chrome, works very well in it. But hangs in firefox. Why is that?